# VS2005, 2008 - ASP.NET Browser Settings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

How can I choose/change which browser to start when I run an ASP.NET Web application in VS2005 or VS2008?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to choose File -> Browse with. That works for me when switching between IE and Firefox. You can use it to change the default browser to start with.

Just make sure you select the ASPX page you want to start on first, otherwise the menu item won't appear.

If you want to use the keyboard ALT F then ALT H works.

Answer (score 1):

Within the Solution Explorer, right click on a file and select "Browse With..." You can choose the default browser in the popup window.

Answer (score 1):

1.Go to Solution Explorer in Visual Studio.

2.Right click on a page, choose **Browse With...**

[right click web page file http://img146.imageshack.us/img146/9766/rclick.png](http://img146.imageshack.us/img146/9766/rclick.png)

3.You are shown the installed browsers on your system. The one marked as (Default) will be the one that Visual Studio will launch when running/debugging.

[browsers http://img149.imageshack.us/img149/8290/58135129.png](http://img149.imageshack.us/img149/8290/58135129.png)

4.Select the browser you'd like to be launched by default, and hit the **Set As Default** button. Click the **Browse** button.

5.If the browser that you'd like to run is not on the list, hit the **Add** button. For example, this system has Google Chrome installed, but it's not currently on the list.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the default web browser for windows. Best way is to open you browser of choice and go to the options where you can usually find a "Set this as default browser" option.

Otherwise look at the windows default programs config.

Answer (score 0):

By default Visual Studio will use whatever the default browser is on your computer.  Switching your browser to a different default will change this.

Alternatively you can you can do this through the Project property pages.

Right Click on your project and select Properties.  Go to the Web tab.  Switch the Start Action to "Start External Program" and choose your web browser.